# How can I get better at this certain kind of probability problem?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm studying for an onsite interview with Google for a product manager position. While looking at interview questions online, I've realized that I really need to brush up on the probability and statistics that I once knew well in college -- marbles, cards, dice, etc. I'm expecting questions like this one:

> If the probability of observing a car in 30 minutes on a highway is 0.95, what is the probability of observing a car in 10 minutes (assuming constant default probability)?

What's a good way to find a lot of problems at this level? I'd like to try to do several per day between now and the interview (which is a couple weeks away). Are there any good books of problems like this? I don't *think* I need to study permutations/combinations or types of distributions or anything like that, so a general prob/stat textbook isn't really what I need. I don't really know how to characterize those problems well enough to search for them.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a poisson distribution problem, you may want to look into that. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: I think you can also consider each of 10 minutes to be a Bernoulli trial, because it asks for "a car", which means that only the event of 0 cars is in the complement.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a Schaum's Outline of Probability, which contains a bunch of problems with full solutions. I'm not sure if this would be above or below the level you are looking for...